# Replace images in Adobe Flash

Tags: button, replace, frame

I am trying to make a nike id concept based flash application. It is almost the same as this one url: [http://store.nike.com/nl/en_gb/product/free-trainer-5-v5-id/?piid=36192&pbid=347544781&intpromo=free:nikeid-lp:p1:freetr5.0-3shoes-greenwhite](http://store.nike.com/nl/en_gb/product/free-trainer-5-v5-id/?piid=36192&pbid=347544781&intpromo=free%3anikeid-lp%3ap1%3afreetr5.0-3shoes-greenwhite)

But not the identical because what I would like to make is that not the color changes but that the image replaces itself with another image out of my project.

I already have a button but what's only left is that it have to do something like written above.

If you know how to help me, please reply.

Thanks.